# ChainerによるDeep-Learning

Tags: python, cuda, chainer, 深層学習

実行環境はMAC OSX EL CAPITANでpyenvの上にanaconda2.4.0を導入したものです。
GPUはGeForceの下位モデルを搭載しており、CUDAは7.0です。

Chainerを用いてディープラーニングを行おうとしていますがうまく行きません。            
http://qiita.com/hogefugabar/items/312707a09d29632e7288 を参考に、データを読み込みクラス数、データ数をだすところまではうまくいきました。
参考ページと同じコード、データを用いCNN.pyとanimeface.pyとmain.pyの3つを同じディレクトリに置きました。main.pyを実行すると

```
AnimeFaceDataset instance has no attribute 'read_data_target'
```

のエラーが出ます。
ちなみにmain.pyは

```
from CNN import CNN
from animeface import AnimeFaceDataset
from chainer import cuda

#cuda.init(0)
cuda.check_cuda_available()

print 'load AnimeFace dataset'
dataset = AnimeFaceDataset()
dataset.read_data_target()
data = dataset.data
target = dataset.target
n_outputs = dataset.get_n_types_target()

cnn = CNN(data=data,
          target=target,
          gpu=0,
          n_outputs=n_outputs)

cnn.train_and_test(n_epoch=100)
```

とcuda.init(0)をcuda.check_cuda_available()に書き換えてあります。

参照ページの下にも別の方がした同じ質問が載っていますが、長らく答えられていないようです。わかる方がいらっしゃいましたらよろしくお願い致します。

****追記****
無事解決しました。ありがとうございます。
今度は

```
cuda driver version is insufficient for cuda runtime version
```

のエラーが出て悩まされています。
いろいろ調べOpenCVのインストール、ドライバのアップデート、パス通し、ターミナルから実行などやりましたが効果なしです。
詳しい方いらっしゃいましたらよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 昔の質問に対するコメントになってしまいますが、別のエラーに対する質問は別個の質問として投稿するのが良いと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AnimeFaceDataset`クラスを見てみると`read_data_target`ではなく`load_data_target`と定義されていますので、これで動くと思います。

```
dataset.load_data_target()
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。この点については一発で解決しました。